# Put double quotes in a mysql string with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code in PHP:

```
$_pagi_sql='SELECT * FROM programas WHERE MATCH(titulo, texto,pais) AGAINST ('"$criterio"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND operador=34 And validez >= NOW()';
```

I want to put exactly this string in the variable $_pagi_sql:

```
SELECT * FROM programas WHERE MATCH(titulo, texto,pais) AGAINST ('"STH"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND operador=34 And validez >= NOW()
```

However the double quotes are not properly stored in the variable $_pagi_sql

How can it be done?

Comment: Escape the double quotes i.e. AGAINST ('\"STH\"' IN B...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter double quotes by adding slashes before your single quotes.

```
$_pagi_sql='SELECT * FROM programas WHERE MATCH(titulo, texto,pais) AGAINST (\'"$criterio"\' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND operador=34 And validez >= NOW()';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the single quotes from right handle side with double quotes:

```
$_pagi_sql="SELECT * FROM programas WHERE MATCH(titulo, texto,pais) AGAINST ('\"$criterio\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND operador=34 And validez >= NOW()";
```

Or, get rid of the quotes, use heredoc:

```
$_pagi_sql = <<<SQL
SELECT * FROM programas WHERE MATCH(titulo, texto,pais) AGAINST ('"$criterio"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND operador=34 And validez >= NOW()
SQL;
```

Comment: This won't produce the double quotes around the variable that the OP has in the desired output.